# Xampp Apache not able to access port 80 even though it's not in use

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, xampp, port

These are  the error message I get while trying to run Apache from Xampp control panel. I am using Windows 8 and XAMPP Version: 1.8.2

Error Message :

> The Apache service named reported the following error:
>   (OS 10013) An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80

I have already tried these solutions but no use :

1. Changed the port no to 8080 in httpd.conf and httpd_ssl.conf
2. In cmd checked netstat -a -n-o | find "80"  but port 80 is not in use.
3. In httpd.conf the DocumentRoot and <Directory> entries are pointing to existing folders.
4. Skype , IIS is disabled.
5. Firewall has valid inbound rule to allow access .
6. Uninstalled and reinstalled the Xampp .

Control Panel error:

[image: Control Panel error]

Windows event view error:

[image: Windows event view error]

Comment: I had problems with Xampp and Skype together. Both uses port 80.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread. I don't have enough reps to upvote. :( But after 2 hours of troubleshooting, changing the http.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files for the listener and port references to 8080, and still getting this error, but @afkari got it.  Running XAMPP as administrator resolved my issue (Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

> . . . made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions . . .

Do you run xampp with **administrator** access in windows 8.* ?

Xampp on windows 8 need **administrator access** to work correctly.

Follow there steps :

1. Locate the program icon or a shortcut in Windows Explorer.
2. Right-click the program icon or shortcut, and then click **Run as administrator**.
3. When the UAC message is displayed, do one of the following:

   - If you are logged on as a standard user, or if UAC is configured to    always require credentials, enter the appropriate administrative    credentials, and then click **OK**.
   - If you are logged on as an administrator and UAC is not configured to always require credentials, click **Yes** to start the application.

OR

You can use this link on microsoft website :

> **[run an application once with a full administrator access](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token)**